# Merge two datasets in R with conditions

Tags: r, date, merge, dataset, conditional-statements

I have a question about merging two datasets in R with conditions.

The first dataset shows which airport runway (Runway) was used on which date and whether a plane arrived or departed from that runway (A/D).

Dataset 1:

```
Date      Runway   Arrival/Departure
01-01-08    89      A
01-01-08    120     A
01-01-08    97      D
01-01-09    89      A
01-02-09    92      D
01-02-10    89      A
```

The second dataset describes the number of complaints per runway and per arrival/departure. For instance, the complaints for the second dataset belong to runway 89 and arrival (A) (though this is not mentioned in the second dataset itself as you can see).

Dataset 2:

```
Date       Complaints
01-01-08    12
01-01-09    15
01-02-10    53
```

Now I want to add the second data set to the first one, again based on date. Moreover,  I want the values of the complaints of dataset 2 to be linked with Runway 89 and arrival of dataset 1. The complaints for the other runways and arrival/ departure will thus become NA.

This is an example of the final dataset that I want to create:

```
Date       Runway   A/D     Complaints
01-01-08    89      A       12
01-01-08    120     A       NA
01-01-08    97      D       NA
01-01-09    89      A       15
01-02-09    92      D       NA
01-02-10    89      A       53
```

I thought that this would work with an if statement: if runway 89 and arrival, merge dataset based on date. But I have not obtained the desired result yet and I have no idea how to proceed. Simply merging also did not work, for that will give give complaints for all the runways, but I only want it linked with runway 89 and arrival.

If anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: a quick fix is to add Runway and A/D to Dataset2?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! The entire dataset consists of more complaint files (so for instance also for Runway 120, A), etc, so I'm not sure if I can do that, because it would still not be properly linked then?

Comment: how do you know that Dataset2 is for 89, A?

Comment: I have obtained a few open source data files dat specify which complaint dataset belongs to which runway and arrival/departure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: So when you read in each dataset2, you must have specify each runway and a/d each time. You could have reconstructed your output without dataset1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this in mind:

Form data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c("01-01-08","01-01-08","01-01-08","01-01-09","01-02-09","01-02-10"),Runway=c(89,120,97,89,92,89),AD=c("A","A","D","A","D","A"))
df2 <- data.frame(Date=c("01-01-08","01-01-09","01-02-10"),Complaints=c(12,15,53))
```

Merge by date

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by="Date",all.x=T)
```

Simple loop for removing irrelevant values

```
for(i in 1:6)
  {
  if(df3$Runway[i]==89)df3Complaints[i] else df3$Complaints[i] <- NA
}
```

You can also include the Arrival/Departure variable in the loop if your original working data contains departures from gate 89 and you don't want those to be associated with the complaints:

```
for(i in 1:6)
  {
  if(df3$Runway[i]==89 && df3$AD[i]=="A")df3Complaints[i] else df3$Complaints[i] <- NA
}
```

Comment: no need for a `for` loop imo: `df3[df3$Runway != 89, 'Complaints'] <- NA` works just fine

Comment: You are correct. I, however, like to live on the edge.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Veraaa consider accepting this answer as the correct solution by checking the green tick mark under the score. It should turn green.